# Make a KeyEvent update JLabel in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, keylistener

I'm trying to use Java's KeyListener to update a JLabel as I type. Essentially, I'm making my own text field. Here's what I have:

```
/**
     * Constructor for objects of class Dictionary
     */
    public Dictionary()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Shori Dictionary");
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

private void createWord()
    {
        frame.remove(pane);
        pane = new PaintPane(field.getImage());
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();

        newWord = new JLabel(text);
        newWord.setFont(newWord.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 28));
        newWord.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        newWord.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);
        newWord.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        newWord.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
        newWord.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(445, 150, 0, 0));
        pane.add(newWord);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pane.setFocusable(true);
        updateInteraction();
    }

    private void keyPress()
    {
        pane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                for(int i = 97; i <= 122; i++){
                    //Cycles through every lowercase letter
                    if(e.getKeyChar() == (char)(i)&& pane.returnImage() == field.getImage()){
                        text += (char)(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //Even in the Debugger, these next if-elses have never worked
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE&& pane.returnImage() == field.getImage()) text += " ";
                else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE&& pane.returnImage() == field.getImage()){
                    int x = text.length();
                    text = text.substring(0,x-1); //Not sure if this works, haven't been able to test it yet
                }
                else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER&& pane.returnImage() == field.getImage()){
                    //do something with the text
                    text = "";
                    //exit the word creator
                }
                newWord.setText(text);
                newWord.repaint(); //Apparently this isn't necessary...
            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        }
        );
    }

    private void mouseAction()
    {
        pane.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                //cover page
                if(open.contains(arg0.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == cover.getImage()) displayPages();
                else if(search.contains(arg0.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == cover.getImage()) searchWord();
                else if(enter.contains(arg0.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == cover.getImage()) createWord();
                //inner pages
                else if(nextPage.contains(arg0.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == pages.getImage()) pageFlip("next");
                else if(prevPage.contains(arg0.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == pages.getImage()) pageFlip("previous");
                else if(cancel.contains(arg0.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == field.getImage()) coverPage();
                frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }
        }
        );
    }

    private void mouseMovement()
    {
        pane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                if(search.contains(e.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == cover.getImage()){
                    frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                }
                else if(enter.contains(e.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == cover.getImage()){
                    frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                }
                else if(open.contains(e.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == cover.getImage()){
                    frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                }
                else if(nextPage.contains(e.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == pages.getImage()){
                    frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                }
                else if(prevPage.contains(e.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == pages.getImage()){
                    frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                }
                else if(cancel.contains(e.getPoint())&& pane.returnImage() == field.getImage()){
                    frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                }
                else{
                    frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        }
        );
    }

    private void updateInteraction(){
        mouseMovement();
        mouseAction();
        keyPress();
    }

    public class PaintPane extends JPanel {
        private Image background;
        private Graphics g2d;

        public PaintPane(Image image) {
            background = image;            
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(0, 0) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(this), background.getHeight(this));            
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            if (background != null) {                
                Insets insets = getInsets();

                int width = getWidth() - 1 - (insets.left + insets.right);
                int height = getHeight() - 1 - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

                int x = (width - background.getWidth(this)) / 2;
                int y = (height - background.getHeight(this)) / 2;

                g.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
            }

            //g.fillRect(654, 798, 358, 77); //for testing rectangle positioning
        }

        public Image returnImage() {
            return background;
        }
    }
```

I'm using BluJ to write this, and it has a built in Debugger. I just tried adding `keyPress();` before the `updateInteraction();` in createWord(), and ran the Debugger to go through each method step by step. Everything worked perfectly. Then I tried without the Debugger, and it wouldn't display any text while I was typing. So, I turned on the Debugger again. It didn't detect any keys being typed at all. I don't know why it only worked that once, but it was definitely working. This is my first time working with KeyListener, MouseListener, and MouseMotionListener. Is there a better way to get this program to run properly?

Comment: Do you want to add KeyListener to PaintPane or maybe to JTextField?

Comment: @alex2410: A KeyListener to a JTextField? That would be extremely low on my to-do list. I'd first try a DocumentListener or DocumentFilter before even considering (if ever) a KeyListener.

Comment: The problem is, `KeyListener` will only raise events when the component they are registered to have focus.  It's not enough to simply make the component focusable, you need to request focus as wel

Comment: For the future use KeyAdapter and MouseAdapter instead of MouseListener  and KeyListener.

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do you do that? Like I said, this is my first time working with listeners.

Comment: @alex2410 That doesn't matter.  It's like saying drink 1% milk instead of 2% milk. :P

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'll try looking into a DocumentListener. You're the second one to suggest that.

Comment: Look up `JComponent#requestFocusInWindow`

Comment: @MikeClark It's more readable and shorter))

Comment: @Radi0actvChickn, A DocumentListener only works with Swing components, not something you create. Seems to me like you are in over your head a little here.  You don't understand how focus works, the character typed is part of the KeyEvent, so I don't understand your looping logic in the listener. You should probably spend time learning Swing basics before attempting to write your own component.

Comment: @Radi0actvChickn Please have a look at my answer.  It has a self-contained ready-to-compile-and-run example of how to register a key listener on a panel, draw some information about the struck keys onto the panel, and print other useful information about the events.  Also see my comments about keyPressed/keyReleased vs. keyTyped.

Answer (score 3):

> and it wouldn't display any text while I was typing

A component needs to have focus in order to respond to KeyEvents. A JPanel is not focusable by default.

> I'm making my own text field

Why? What functionality is missing from JTextField?

I would just use JTextField and then add a DocumentListener to the document from the text field. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I wanted to try this. I didn't use JTextField on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just doing a learning exercise, then it's OK to make your own implementation instead of using JTextField.  You can make a JPanel receive key events by calling `setFocusable(true)` on it.

Even after that, you should be aware of something that will probably trip you up:  `keyTyped` callbacks don't fill out the `keyCode` property of `KeyEvent`s.  This is because it's possible to type in characters that do not have a single associated key.  For example, on Windows you can fire keyPressed once by typing ALT+0160.  You hit 5 keys but entered one character (a space) and got a single `keyPressed` callback.

To summarize:  `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` deliver `keyCode`s and *might* deliver `keyChar`.  `keyTyped` never gets a `keyCode`, and always gets a `keyChar`.

```
public class PanelKeyListener extends JFrame {

    private JPanel _contentPane;
    StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PanelKeyListener frame = new PanelKeyListener();
                    frame.setSize(400, 400);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public PanelKeyListener() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        _contentPane = new JPanel() {
            protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
                g.drawString(_stringBuilder.toString(), 10, 20);
            }
        };
        setContentPane(_contentPane);
        _contentPane.setFocusable(true);
        _contentPane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("keyTyped char[" + e.getKeyChar()
                        + "] code[" + e.getKeyCode() + "]");
                _stringBuilder.append(e.getKeyChar());
                _contentPane.repaint();
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("keyReleased char[" + e.getKeyChar()
                        + "] code[" + e.getKeyCode() + "]");
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("keyPressed char[" + e.getKeyChar()
                        + "] code[" + e.getKeyCode() + "]");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You shouldn't reinvent the wheel if you can avoid it.  Use/extend JTextField if it's practical to do so and meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Component must have the [focus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) for keyboard input on `Key Event`. However, to check it in action, first make your `JPanle` focus-able by  `panel.setFocusable(true)`. Then try with `panel.requestFocusInWindow()` 
to get the focus to panel on application start-up.

However, in your code:

```
for(int i = 97; i <= 122; i++){
                    //Cycles through every lowercase letter
                    if(e.getKeyChar() == (char)(i)&& pane.returnImage() == field.getImage()){
                        text += (char)(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Why do you have to use a loop here?  Just simply putting:

```
if(evt.getKeyChar() >=97 && evt.getKeyChar() <=122 && pane.returnImage() == field.getImage())
    text += evt.getKeyChar()
```

Should do the work.